# Why does Javascript's instanceof return true for these native constructors?

Tags: javascript, prototype

This is on Mozilla Firefox web console;

```
> Function instanceof Function;
>true

>Array instanceof Function;
>true

>String instanceof Function
>true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because all constructors are functions, and `Function`, `Array`, and `String` are all constructors (i.e., you use `new` with them).

Answer (score 1):

Typically people don't use the constructors for these types, opting instead for literals like `[]`, `""`, and `function(){}`. However, you can create strings, arrays, and functions using their constructor methods:

```
var str = new String("Hello World");
```

Note that we're calling a function - the string constructor. The same is the case with arrays:

```
var arr = new Array("Hello", "World");
```

Again, calling a function. These are all instances of Function because we used their constructor. This isn't the case with literals:

```
var str = "Hello World";
console.log( str instanceof Function ); // false

var arr = ["Hello", "World"];
console.log( arr instanceof Function ); // false
```